# How to get a Seagate 2 TB USB drive automounted?

Tags: debian, mount, usb-drive, file-browser

I got a Seagate Backup Plus 2 TB sometime back. I tried getting it to be auto-mounted and read by Nautilus.caja or any other file-browser. The external HDD is ntfs and I have installed ntfs-3g. I have couple of Expansion USB drives and they are detected by nautilus and others quite easily. On the CLI I get the following output :-

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

As can be seen there are few USB 1.1 ports and few 2.0 ports. As can
be seen Seagate attaches and declares itself at Bus 005 Device 003: ID
0bc2:ab24 .

I also checked via fdisk -l and got the following :-

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc5f7c5f7

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1               63  102398309  102398247  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        102398371 1953523711 1851125341 882.7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        102398373  204796619  102398247  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6  *     204797952  595421183  390623232 186.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7        595423232  790732799  195309568  93.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8        790734848 1943076863 1152342016 549.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       1943078912 1953523711   10444800     5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1bc6b3bc

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048  952322047  952320000 454.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2        952322048 1904642047  952320000 454.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       1904642048 2856962047  952320000 454.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       2856962048 3907026943 1050064896 500.7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       2856964096 3907026943 1050062848 500.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Except for /dev/sdb4 which says it's W95 the rest of them seem to be
ok. Then why it is that the disk does not automount ? I have ano idea also W95 stands for.

I also saw this http://changelog.complete.org/archives/9299-has-modern-linux-lost-its-way-some-thoughts-on-jessie

Could that be a related problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to look long and hard and finally understood what was happening. This is an old system so when no devices are there it gives :-

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

So got to know that one of the ports is a 2.0 port. But because of the way (weird way) it is in GNU/Linux you have to physically put the HDD in the right port to get it mounted. I tried it first with using a USB 1.1 on all the ports but that one didn't give the answer.

So after couple of tries got it :-

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 046: ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 014: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

as it got automatically mounted, it seems it was a non-issue, just had to plug it in the right port (bottom right).

```
$ mount | grep fuse
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/shirish/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I did find an interesting post during my research which I think needs sharing.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=101084&p=700965

So with that post, apparently even a 1.1 port can be made to work a USB 3.0 device.